# Cookies from php being received but not set in browser

Tags: php, angular, cookies

Got a simple Apache server running a php script

```
<?php
setcookie("TestCookie", 50, time()+10, "/", "http://localhost:80", false, false);
echo json_encode("blah");
?>
```

With a .htaccess file that looks like this

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:4200"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

And a http call in an Angular service that looks like this

```
test(): Observable<JSON> {
    return this.http.get<JSON>("http://localhost:80/project/testing.php", {withCredentials: true});
}
```

The problem isn't that I'm not receiving the cookie, as I can see it when I click on the `Cookies` tab in the request to `testing.php`. The problem is that the browser isn't storing it. When I click on site settings to see the cookies in use, it's missing. And when I enter in `document.cookie` into the console, I get an empty string in return.

[image: cookie]

[image: site settings]

[image: console]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting the domain parameter in the `setcookie()` method to be an empty string, I'm now seeing the cookie appear in Chrome's "cookies in use" popup and in the console after doing `document.cookie`. I guess setting a value in the domain parameter messed everything up for some reason.